# ngx-datatable ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I am attempting to install ngx-datatables in a project running Angular 12
npm install @swimlane/ngx-datatable
After install I get the following Errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: Optylab-project@0.0.1    
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.2" from @swimlane/ngx-datatable@19.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm ERR!   @swimlane/ngx-datatable@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I don't understand what needs to be done here.

Comment: This means the following: your project uses `@angular/common@~12.0.x`, requires `@swimlane/ngx-datatable@~19.0.x` which uses `@angular/common@^11.x.x` (**NOT** 12). There is no overlap in version for `@angular/common`. So as long as `ngx-datatable` has no release for angular 12, your application will be stuck at angular 11, unless you `force` install `@swimlane/ngx-datatable@~19.0.x`. But when you checkout the project somewhere else, you will again have to run `npm install --force @swimlane/ngx-datatable@19.0.0` manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Master branch [not updated to Angular 12](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/2008) yet. You can try to install with `--force` flag::

```
npm i @swimlane/ngx-datatable --save --force
```

Comment: Nothing change I still can't import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
This command didn't install ngxdtable in nodemodule

Comment: @oussema-kallel Do you have previous errors?

Comment: I got this 
up to date, audited 1673 packages in 12s

131 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Comment: @oussema-kallel You are right. I updated my answer. You can try to install one more time.

Comment: you might need to run "npm install" and restart "ng s"

Answer (score 1):

Installing `@swimlane/ngx-datatable@20.0.0` helped in my case